# Splitting Lines in Python in a List?

Tags: python, function, class

I'm new-ish to Python and I'm having trouble achieving a result that I want. I'm opening a text file called urldata.txt which contains URLs that I need to break down by scheme, server, and path.

I have retrieved the data from the file:

```
urls = open("urldata.txt").read()
print(urls)
```

this returns:

```
http://www.google.com

https://twitter.com/search?q=%23ASUcis355

https://github.com/asu-cis-355/course-info
```

I want to break these URLs into 3 pieces each so that when I enter

```
urls.scheme()
urls.server()
urls.path()
```

It will return me the scheme of each URL when I enter

```
urls.scheme()

'http','https','https'
```

Then it will return the server when I enter

```
urls.server()

'google.com'
'twitter.com'
'github.com'
```

Finally, it will return the path when I enter

```
urls.path() 

'/'
'/search?q=%23ASUcis355'
'/asu-cis-355/course-info'
```

I have defined a class to do this; however, I receive an error saying 'scheme() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' Below is my class and the def parts to it that I have created.

```
class urls:
    def __init__(self,url):
        self.urls=urls
    def scheme(self):
        return urls.split("://")[0]
    def server(self):
        return urls.split("/")[2]
    def path(self):
        return urls.split(".com/")[1]
```

Any help at all is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This exists already. It's called [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

d = urlparse('https://twitter.com/search?q=%23ASUcis355')
print(d)
```

Output:

```
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='twitter.com', path='/search', params='', query='q=%23ASUcis355', fragment='')
```

Comment: Hello @idjaw. While this is completely the right way to do this in industry I'm pretty sure this a homework problem and the point is to have the student go through the string parsing themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you attempt to call a class definition (what urls' is) without creating an instance of this class in Python3 then you get this error

```
>>> urls.scheme()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: scheme() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
>>>
```

But if you create an instance of urls and then use that instance this works as intended

```
>>> url_instance = urls("http://www.google.com")
>>> url_instance.scheme()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in scheme
AttributeError: type object 'urls' has no attribute 'split'
```

Note that this fixes your current error but your code isn't correct as is. I'll leave you to figure out what's happening with this error.

The difference between a class definition (or type) and an instance of the class has some interesting nuance but generally speaking

```
class Thing:
     pass
```

is a class definition and

```
thing_instance = Thing()
```

Is an instance of the class.